# Linux kill Java Process from java console application

Tags: java, linux, process, java-8, processbuilder

I'm trying to kill off a already running java process using the Name of the .jar file.

It works completely fine when running the command

> pkill -9 -f myapp.jar

from terminal but it doesn't work when you run that same command in a ProcessBuilder.

```
BufferedReader killStream;
String line;

     try{
        String[] args = new String[] {"pkill", "-9", "-f", " myapp.jar"}; 
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        killStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        line = killStream.readLine();

        System.out.println(line);

        return true;
     }catch(Exception e){

         e.printStackTrace();
          return false;

     }
```

killStream always return **'null'**

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe not related, but try to remove the extra space in `" myapp.jar"` .

Comment: lmfao. thanks for pointing that out. I definitely need to get some sleep.

Comment: Does the process get killed?

Comment: Note that your code will not display all the output of the execution of the command. You're effectively printing out only the first line.

Comment: @EmreDalkiran yes, it worked

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Noted mate! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few missing points here, aside from what is mentioned above regarding the passing in of the arguments your code could do with some more refining.

First of all why not use a try with resources clause to make sure that your resources are managed automatically and get always closed correctly?

With this in mind your code would look like:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    // code to parse the command's output.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // code to handle exceptions
}
```

Secondly, with the current code your method will always return true even if the `pkill` command has not run correctly.

Ideally would should wait for the process to terminate using `Process#waitFor` and then invoke `Process#exitValue` to retrieve the exit status of the command. Then you should return true or false based on whether the exit code is 0 or anything else.

Finally in order to be a bit more efficient, I would suggest using a `StringBuilder` to collect and append all of the process's output lines and just printing out that String.

Note that there are even better methods to encapsulate all this procedures making it more generic and re-usable while also using Java 8+ API (like streams, consumers etc etc).